# Tagging the 2013 MacPro6,1

Tags: discussion, tags

So, the MacPro6,1 doesn't seem to have a tag it belongs to — the [tag wiki for `mac-pro`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/mac-pro/info) mentions, by date, all of the models *except* the new, completely-revised, 2013 model (and with good reason. It's basically an entirely new product line, to be honest. Not a tower, not customizable, no disc drive, no rackmount possibilities … etc etc etc.); which implies to me that it's speaking of the “old form-factor” Mac Pros.

Should we create a new tag for `mac-pro-2013`, or possibly rename the current one to `mac-pro-tower` or something like that? If not, the tag-wiki should be updated to make it clear that it also applies to the 2013+ Mac Pro models.

Answer (score 2):

The tag wiki is also missing the June 2012 Mac Pro. In my opinion, it's just an outdated tag wiki and [mac-pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-pro) should be used for every Mac Pro including the June 2012 and 2013 models not mentioned on the tag wiki.

I don't think a separate tag is really necessary to distinguish between the legacy Mac Pro models and the current design, but I'm also not against the idea. However, I would prefer tagging questions regarding the legacy design with a renamed tag such as [mac-pro-legacy](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-pro-legacy) and the current Mac Pro being tagged with [mac-pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-pro), since I don't think we should be using anything but the product title for current products.

Side note: Hardware tags are misused as it is — briefly checking the first couple of [mac-pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-pro) questions yields things such as "How to make Siri available when I open my MacBook?
[macbook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macbook)[mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac)[sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sierra)[mac-pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mac-pro)[siri](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/siri)", where all the hardware tags are inappropriate.

Comment: Hm, you make a good point. I *do think* moving the old Mac Pro to a new tag is a good idea; because when *properly* used to tag hardware-specific / hardware-related questions, they're pretty substantially different machines - but it's really not a priority thing, because you're right, they look widely mis-used. /=

Comment: George raises a great point about the tags being deployed very poorly and inefficiently. If we were to do an audit of 25 random questions tagged with a specific tag and most are wrongly used - merging the bad tags to a larger bin might help people know what or when to use them.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the opinion that we should aggressively flatten all tags for hardware. But I'm open to an explanation of how in practice it works well on another site. Or an example where it works well here.

The example I have is MacBook and MacBook Pro and Air and such. Do you tag the generation or the size of the screen or the CPU or if it has SSD or HDD when that was a thing? It ends up taking two to three tags for the precise questions when you can usually search the MacBook tag and then the term for what you really want.

Thinking more deeply, people really don't often want to ask about a MacBook pro itself - it's almost always going to be about upgrade or port or what not and then we could be tagging on the specific item in question for the best locality if you're looking for a narrow tag to follow or search.

The side effect of general tags is that the wikis require less maintenance if they merit a tag wiki or summary at all. The wikis should be about how to use the tag and duplicating usage for MacPro across all the models Apple has and will release seems like a lot of duplication of work for little payoff.

Good question though +1 for raising the discussion. I can see it might not be an easy one to pick an answer for many. Even though I lean one way - I'm open to new inputs or opinions on this topic specifically and generally.